# Load node entities by owner

Tags: users, database, 9

I want to load entities by their owner. This is what I have so far:

```
\Drupal::logger('migrate_users')->notice("Hello start");
$userStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');

$query = $userStorage->getQuery();
$uids = $query
  ->condition('status', '1')
  ->condition('type', 'student')
  ->execute();

$users = $userStorage->loadMultiple($uids);

// help regarding this line
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties([
      'type' => 'article',
      'user' => SOME_USER,
    ]);

\Drupal::logger('dssi_migrate_users')->notice("done");
```

What do I need to pass in for `SOME_USER`?

Answer (score 2):

You are only using the wrong property name for passing the user ID.

The following would work:

```
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties([
      'type' => 'article',
      'uid' => SOME_USER_ID,
    ]);
```

If you wish to fetch entities from several users, just use an array:

```
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties([
      'type' => 'article',
      'uid' => [uid1, uid2, uid3],
    ]);
```

`loadByProperties()` method use [buildPropertyQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AbuildPropertyQuery/9.3.x)() to pass the values to the query, which use a "IN" condition.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `IN` operation and I think `loadByProperties` method only acts on `Equals` operation so, use `getQuery` method instead and you can attach as many conditions as you want, like below:

```
$nodeQuery = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
$entities = $nodeQuery->condition('bundle', 'article')->condition('uid', $uids, 'IN')->execute();
```

Comment: your solution is right but I think it is unnecessary in that case. According to the docs, [loadByProperties()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/9.3.x) uses buildPropertyQuery() method, which uses `IN` to build its conditions.